# How to calculate the number of rows in a Cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rows, cell-array

I want to calculate the number of rows in a Cell array in MATLAB.
I use the code below to count the number of columns in a cell array but I do not know its way for counting the rows.

```
filledCells = ~cellfun(@isempty,a);
columns = sum(filledCells,2)
```

As an example, i've got x as a cell array:

```
x =     [5]    [1x8 double]    [5]
```

This cell array has one row and three columns. I need a code to calculate the number of rows equal to "1" , but I did not find a way to calculate it.

Comment: Can you give an example? What are the contents of the cell array `a`?

Comment: Inferring from the way you are calculating number of cols:

`sum(filledCells)`

for number of rows.

Comment: @Oleg it did not work

Comment: Your questionwas not clear, proof 4 answers when the solution is trivial. If you provided the example with `x` in the first place, you would have had the asnwet within 1 min. To avoid future confusion, "number of rows IN a cell array" might refer to the content of the cell array. Therefore, to avoid confusion remember that the cell array is a wrapper, and it's content can be anything, thus use "size OF a cell array".

Comment: @Oleg If i knew the answer was in the size of the array then i would not ask the question at all. i just wanted to know the number of rows in a cell array which i think it's clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used most of ideas but it did not work then with the help of what herohuyongtao said i reach to this idea which worked properly

```
 [nr,nc]=size(x)
```

Which nr is the number of rows
thanks all of you.

Comment: Now I know what you mean. Yes, this will work. How simple is that! :)

Comment: @ herohuyongtao Yes,that was so simple,thanks to you

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more general approach: works for rows or columns, and takes into account the size of each cell:

```
dim = 1; %// 1 for rows, 2 for columns
result = sum(cellfun(@(c) size(c,dim), a), dim);
```

Example:

```
>> a = {1, [2 3], []; 4, [], 5}
a = 
    [1]    [1x2 double]     []
    [4]              []    [5]
>> dim = 1;
```

gives

```
>> result = sum(cellfun(@(c) size(c,dim), a), dim)
result =
     2     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
%% "a" is the cell array, total num of rows will be saved in "rows"
num = length(a); % num of objects in "a" - big rows
rows = 0;
for i=1:num
    [r c] = size(C{i})
    rows = rows+r;
end
```

Comment: it wont work properly for all examples like x{1,1}=[2 3 4] , x{1,2}=[2],x{1,3}=[2 3 4]

Comment: @SaraDean I just tested in MATLAB, it worked perfectly. It returns `rows=3`, right?

Comment: @SaraDean Why not 3? It does has 3 rows. I don't get it.

Comment: may be i'm wrong!? x{rows,columns} is it wrong? x{1,1:3} means one row and three columns,right?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to get the first dimension of the size.

```
rowCount = size(x,1)
```